# Index is not used in MySQL even if the query contains an index hint

Tags: mysql, indexing

- MySQL 5.6

Consider the following table:

```
create table mytbl (
    id long primary key,
    digest varchar(32)
);
```

The `digest` column contains MD5 digest and I created index on `digest` by:

```
create fulltext index digest on mytbl (digest);
```

I subsequently check a query:

```
explain select count(id) from mytbl where digest = 'abcde12345ffhhg';  -- a digest in the table
```

The plan is (the table has 1000 rows):

```
id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | extra
1  | SIMPLE      | mytbl | ALL  | digest        | NULL| NULL    | NULL| 1000 | Using where
```

I then called the query

```
explain select count(id) from mytbl use index (digest) where digest = 'abcde12345ffhhg';
```

But the plan remained the same, i.e. the index `digest` is not used.

Why does MySQL ignore the index set on `digest`?

---

### EDIT

I thought I had a misconception about the option `[fulltext | spatial | unique]` in `CREATE INDEX` statement. I dropped the `fulltext index` and then created a default index (`create index digest ...`). Consequently, MySQL used the `digest` index in the query plan.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but seems to be...from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html  " For FULLTEXT searches, index hints work as follows:    For natural language mode searches, index hints are silently ignored. For example, IGNORE INDEX(i1) is ignored with no warning and the index is still used.  Which may indicate that MySQL is ignoring your index hint.  Still doesn't explain why it doesn't use the index without the hint... but another post I read said that for a low number of rows, MySQL might opt not to use an index, 'of its own accord' so to speak.

Comment: For small number of rows it may be faster to scan the table rather than check an index. Or the statistics might not be up to date.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thanks. The table in the question is just an example. The real table is over 100K rows but the index `digest` was not used at all.

Comment: @Redbeard011010 Thanks a lot. I tried to `explain select` on the column `id` and the `PRIMARY` index was indeed used.

Comment: Try this, please.  `explain select count(id) from mytbl where match(digest) against ('abcde12345ffhhg');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query ignores the fulltext index because it is not explaining the execution plan of a fulltext search.

To instead explain a fulltext search, and engage the index, use `MATCH()...AGAINST()`:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count(id) FROM mytbl WHERE MATCH(digest) AGAINST ('abcde12345ffhhg');
```